# Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) - String index out of range: 51968

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy a `Spring Boot` web application on Weblogic 12.1.3.

When I deploy from the console I get the following errors (on the application)

```
Message icon - Error Unable to access the selected application.
Message icon - Error String index out of range: 51968
Message icon - Error String index out of range: 51968
Message icon - Error String index out of range: 51968
```

On the other hand it deploys successfully from `Intellij IDEA` and the `autodeploy` folder. Also, on other development machines it even deploys successfully from the console, but on others not.

No errors whatsoever on the server logs either.

Any ideas of the cause?

Answer (score 3):

OMG, same problem here.

Funny thing is, when you unzip your application (war) and then again zip that folder - new archive does deploy just fine, no error ...

Comment: So any solution aside from unzip and rezip?

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem. I tried to modify web.xml, and when I changed version to 2.4(3.0 before), it worked. But I still don't know why.

old web.xml

```
<web-app 
    version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
...
</web-app>
```

new web.xml (**it worked**)

```
<web-app 
    version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
...
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I don't know if this helps, but in my case it was the version of **spring-ws-core** maven dependency.

I was using the **3.0.4.RELEASE** and I was having the error, while downgrading to **2.4.3.RELEASE** was the solution to it.

Best regards,