# Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) - String index out of range: 33659

Tags: spring

I tried to deploy build on Weblogic 12.1.3 Server.While deploying it throws 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 33659.
Any ideas of the cause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) - String index out of range: 51968](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099519/weblogic-12c-12-1-3-string-index-out-of-range-51968)